# Keeping Argument/Parameters in same line as much as possible

Tags: clang-format

I'm trying to match my clang-format as close as possible to our eclipse formatter.
In this migration I have realised that eclipse prefers to keep the parameters/arguments in same line as much as possible:
Example:
[image]

If I change BinPackParameters i will either get:

[image]

or:

[image]

I want to have the same behaviour as eclipse:
"Keep putting parameters in same line as function/method name then wrap when column limit is reached"

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
I'm extending Google style

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

1. You shouldn't use images to show us code. No big deal, but it makes it hard for somebody to cut and paste your example code to investigate the problem.
2. I think the setting you're looking for is `AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign`. Given the two inputs you show above, the command `clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: Google,AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign}'` gives:

   ```
     virtual int *XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int *parentaaaa, unsigned int x.unsigned int y,
         int index, int resolution, int zoom);
     virtual int XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int *attrasdasdasd, char *outstr,
         unsigned char mode, unsigned int minlen, unsigned int maxlen);
   ```
3. However, there are cases with `AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign` where `clang-format` will move all parameters to the next line. You may be seeing one of those cases, and I don't believe there is any good workaround for this. Because of this, you may want to use `AlignAfterOpenBrackets: Align` (which is the default for Google style). This doesn't exactly match your Eclipse example, but it is reasonably close most of the time. For example, the command `clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: Google}'` gives:

   ```
     virtual int* XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int* parentaaaa, unsigned int x.unsigned int y,
                                int index, int resolution, int zoom);
     virtual int XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int* attrasdasdasd, char* outstr,
                               unsigned char mode, unsigned int minlen,
                               unsigned int maxlen);
   ```
4. Your `eclipse` example (the first example in your question) has the continuation lines indented further. To exactly match that, you would use `ContinuationIndentWidth: 8`. So the command `clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: Google,AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign, ContinuationIndentWidth: 8}'` gives:

   ```
     virtual int *XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int *parentaaaa, unsigned int x.unsigned int y,
             int index, int resolution, int zoom);
     virtual int XXXXXXXXXXXXX(int *attrasdasdasd, char *outstr,
             unsigned char mode, unsigned int minlen, unsigned int maxlen);
   ```
5. For more information about these style options, see the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).
6. A good place to experiment with style options, and to see what is different between different versions of `clang-format`, is the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/).